# How to aggregate number of records per date from table with two dates?

Tags: mysql

I have following table:

| person | arrival | departure |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 01/01/2022 | 04/01/2022 |
| Ana | 03/01/2022 | 04/01/2022 |
| Ronald | 04/01/2022 | NULL |

And I should get something like:

| date | new_arrived | new_departured |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | 1 | 0 |
| 03/01/2022 | 1 | 0 |
| 04/01/2022 | 1 | 2 |

Could anyone help me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

My idea would be:

```
with temp1 as(
SELECT arrival FROM original_table
WHERE arrival is not null
UNION ALL
SELECT departure FROM original_table
WHERE departure is not null)

SELECT temp1.arrival as date, 
(SELECT Count(arrival) FROM original_table WHERE arrival=date),
( SELECT Count(departure) FROM original_table WHERE departure=date)
FROM temp1
GROUP BY temp1.arrival;
```

Comment: 'this is not the best option to do it,' - why would you say that??

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I said that because there are likely better ways of doing it. However it still achieves the result. If you disagree, I can delete that part.

Comment: UNION without ALL will not produce duplicated records on output